# PHPmailer not sending the notification to the newly registered user

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi I have used a mailer plugin called PHPmailer I have followed everything from its documentation but it doesnt work at all

Here is what I have based on the tutorial that was given to me

```
 include ('mailform/class.phpmailer.php');

    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> MissBrown E-mail </title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-weight:300;font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:18px;margin:0;padding:0;">

    <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
        <thead style="background:#391E03;">
            <th colspan="2" align="justify" style="font-size:14px;color:#FFF;font-weight:400;"> You have a Mail Information from <strong style="text-transform:capitalize;">'.$lname.'</strong>... </th>
        </thead>

        <tbody style="color:#444444">       
            <tr id="introduction">
                <td style="font-size:14px;line-height:26px;width:100%;">
                    <h3>Customer Information</h3>
                    <dl>
                        <dt style="clear:left;float:left;width:160px;font-weight:700;">Full Name</dt>
                        <dd style="text-transform:capitalize;margin-left:180px;">'.$fname.' &nbsp;</dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt style="clear:left;float:left;width:160px;font-weight:700;">Email Address</dt>
                        <dd style="margin-left:180px;">'.$username.' &nbsp;</dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt style="clear:left;float:left;width:160px;font-weight:700;">Phone Number</dt>
                        <dd style="margin-left:180px;">&nbsp;</dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt style="clear:left;float:left;width:160px;font-weight:700;">Feedback / Message</dt>
                        <dd style="margin-left:180px;"> &nbsp;</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>


    </table>

    </body>
    </html>';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsMail(); 

    // send via Mail

    //origin of sender
    $mail->From     = 'service-noreply@email.com';

    //concat name to fullname
    $mail->FromName = ''.$fname.'';

    //Recipient
    $mail->AddAddress($username);
    $mail->AddCC('');
    $mail->AddBCC('');

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Subject  =  'You have a webmail information...';
    $mail->Body     =  $message;
    $mail->AltBody  =  $message;

    if(!$mail->Send()){
     echo "Message was not sent <p>";
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     //exit;
    }
```

any idea where have I gone wrong? the trigger for this script is after a button was clicked every details will be saved on my database and this script along with the database handling was suppose to send a notification to the registered email

Comment: The error is being echoed out at the end, what is it ?

Comment: What does the `echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;` say?

Comment: there was no error being returned

Comment: @user256009 Is it on your local server ?

Comment: yes this was on my local server

Comment: Have you enabled error handling in PHP.ini?

Comment: Did you check your junk folder?

Comment: yeah.. There are errors being thrown but those errors are after I modified something to check if the error handling is enabled

Comment: yeah even on the spam folder no message

Comment: var dump $username what does it give you.

Comment: string(25) "myemail@example.com" was the result

Comment: Try it out with isSendmail instead of isMail

Comment: it gave me this error  `Mailer Error: Could not execute: /var/qmail/bin/sendmail`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51404/discussion-between-patsy-issa-and-user256009)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question was actually simple but I'll explain it  a little first

Everything from the tutorial about PHPmailer is quite true but one thing that I missed was 
the mailer must be uploaded first if you dont have a mail server on your local machine this was the reason why it didn't work for me at first but Thanks to @Patsy Issa suggestion to upload it and try it again. And it did actually work